# List & connect to airplay devices without MPVolumeView

Tags: ios, airplay

I would like to be able to show a list of all supported devices (airplay, chromecast, roku, etc) in the same list.

Regarding airplay the only option I have seen is to use MPVolumeView which itself builds a list of devices and handles the connectivity.

I'd like to have a bit more control over this and the UI.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for something similar but it looks like it still can't be done cleanly outside `MPVolumeView`. Having said that, if you want to get a bit dirty/private then I found two options:

- [Private API usage](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2012/04/23/ios-mirroring-and-programmatic-airplay-selection/)
- [Piggy back off a hidden `MPVolumeView`](https://github.com/priore/AVPlayerOverlay)

Obviously can't use the first one if you're going through the App Store but would work for a private project that Apple don't see. The second is a bit dirty and potentially prone to unexpected breakages. Basically it creates the MPVolumeView but doesn't show it to the user and instead uses its own Airplay button that passes events on to the real one within `MPVolumeView`.